# The Link Assemblies tasks failed unexpectedly Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm creating cross platform app and every time I tried to deploy the app to my android mobile, I'm getting this error. Each time I have to clean build the solution before deploying it. What is the error that causing this problem.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 
>   'C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 
>   2015\Projects\Camera\Camera\Camera.Droid\obj\Debug\linkdst\Camera.Droid.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process. at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access,  Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize,  FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean  bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access) at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.HashFile(String filename,
>   HashAlgorithm hashAlg) at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.HashFile(String
>   filename) at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.HasFileChanged(String source,
>   String destination) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String
>   destination) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.CopyIfChanged(String source,
>   String destination) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build. 
>   BackEnd.ITaskExecution Host.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.
>   d__26.MoveNext() Camera.Droid

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the [known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56275) that a lot of developers experienced.

Make sure you have updated Xamarin to all the latest bits, it should resolve automatically then.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1.Update Xamarin Forms package to 2.5.0.91635.
2.Update all Android Packages to 25.4.0.2.
3.Restart Visual Studio.
4.Delete Bin & Obj folders in Portable & Android.

This worked for me.